# Bcrypt hash is same for different strings

Tags: python, hash, bcrypt

I'm trying to create a hash for 2 longer different strings with **bcrypt** (in python)

This works for shorter strings (like `"a"` and `"b"`), but when I use long string, with the same beginning, it returns the same hash.

I should mention that the salt value stays the same for both strings.

```py
import bcrypt

hash_msg1 = b"1 b'$2b$12$kknL1S6HaV1/DyNiHhV/ue9SPIOAx.qY2iE33QS8.pi8jM0gvZ53a' {'him': -120, 'me': 100}"
hash_msg2 = b"1 b'$2b$12$kknL1S6HaV1/DyNiHhV/ue9SPIOAx.qY2iE33QS8.pi8jM0gvZ53a' {'him': -1, 'me': 1}"

salt = bcrypt.gensalt()

hash1 = bcrypt.hashpw(hash_msg1, salt)
hash2 = bcrypt.hashpw(hash_msg2, salt)

if hash1 == hash2:
    print('Hash is the same')
else:
    print('It works')
```

This prints 'Hash is the same'

I tried using another library called `rsa` in which you can use `rsa.compute_hash(message, 'SHA-256')`.
I tried that with those 2 messages, it worked, but I would like to know how can I do this with **bcrypt**.

(Though I should also mention that hash from the rsa library doesn't use any salt, but I can simply add the salt as a string to the end of the main  string)

It seems like there is a maximum character limit, but I wonder how could I get it to work anyway.

Comment: Does [the recommended workaround](https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/#maximum-password-length) not work?

Comment: @HeapOverflow It actually does, I haven't noticed that there is a published workaround on GitHub, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> The bcrypt algorithm only handles passwords up to 72 characters

https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/

So the fact your documents start with the same sequence of characters means you will get the same hash.

A comment has just appeared above linking to this same content. The docs also contains a workaround. however, that workaround does involve pre-hashing with another library such as RSA so whether you need bcrypt at all will depend on your use-case.

Comment: The point of bcrypt is to be very slow. Using just a fast hash would be missing that point. See the second paragraph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification).

Comment: @SimonN I'm trying to create a blockchain and the content of the string is an index, previous hash and list of transactions (I will use this for proof of work, but that is not yet implemented), should I use the bcrypt library than?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not much of an expert in blockchain or encryption. The points that @HeapOverflow makes above suggest that perhaps bcrypt may be better suited to other use cases, but I'm just speculating.